# How to update extjs4 window's html text on condition

Tags: html, extjs, window

i am working in extjs4. i have window as=

```
addComment : function(btn) {
        var me = this;
        var reviewWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            bodyPadding: '0 0 0 15px',
            cls: 'requestWindowCls',
            style: {
                borderColor: 'white'
            },
            width: 575,
            header : true,
            id: 'addcomment',
            buttonAlign: 'right',
            html : 'Add Comment',...
```

i want to update window's html on condition and want to place that html in header as title which will consist of text along with some icon. So how to perform this in extjs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating window content you can use `reviewWindow.update('HTML content');`

For updating window's header content you can use `reviewWindow.getHeader().update('HTML content');`

Comment: This is further described in the sencha docs. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-update